# Pattern Matching for JavaScript Quiz

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I have a text box answer quiz that I would like to apply 'Pattern Matching' to so, for example, it was case-**insensitive**, slight misspelling was accepted etc...

Can I apply 'i' and [a-z] inside my defined answers below?

```
function init() 
          {

    questions = new Array()
            questions[1] = "What records need to be set up in order to place TV bookings on the system?"
            questions[2] = "What do you need first to spot-match?"

    userAnswers = new Array 
    userAnswers[1] = "c[a-z]t, p[a-z]t, t[a-z]s, c[a-z]n" 
    userAnswers[2] = "t[a-z]e r[a-z]d"


            reference = new Array()
            reference[1] = "C______, P_______, T______s, C_______?"
            reference[2] = "T________ R_________"



          }
```

Any clues and help on this would be very much appreciated... Thanks

Comment: Side notes: 1) Your code falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring its variables. 2) Indexes in arrays in JavaScript and nearly all other programming languages start at 0, not 1. 3) `new Array()` is almost always better written as `[]`. 4) You can initialize the array contents within the `[...]`. 5) Consistent indentation makes your code more readable to you, and to the people whom you're asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below format as per your requirement, hope this helps you.

```
    public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "caaac";
    public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST1 = "taaae";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST.matches("[c][a-z]{4,}"));
    System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST1.matches("[t][a-z]{3}[e]"));
    }
```

You can Refer this link Since you didn`t mention the size of the word so i just given like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this .

```
  function A(input)
  {
 // var code = [c][a-z]{4,};
  var code = [t][a-z]{3}[e];
  if(input.value.match(code))
  {
  alert(Correct..);

  return true;
  }
  else
  {
  alert('Please give correctly');
  return false;
  }
```

}